# Canvas: reset pixels taken into consideration for composite operation

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am currently trying to build a relatively complex application using HTML5 Canvas objects and JS. To efficiently and realistically color areas I want to generate shadow maps based on image masks.

My problem is that the project is highly interactive, and I want to be as efficient as possible - so if anyhow possible I want to stay in one canvas. What I would now like to do is kinda "reset" the pixels taken into consideration for composite operations, so I can draw everything I want to draw onto my canvas, "reset" it (NOT clearing!), draw my mask and draw my shadow map (e. g. using source-in) on top of it.

Is this anyhow possible, or will I have to use a second canvas for this purpose?

Thanks!

Comment: what's the problem in using a second canvas  ? If it avoids some calculations and work, it's probably the most efficient way. (`drawImage` is just one of the fastest methods in canvas API)

Comment: By using a second canvas I have to draw it onto there, get the image data and draw onto my first canvas. In testing this was very slow, as I have quite complicated layered models where many layers need to do this operation often without me being able to cache them.

Comment: Hum I don't see exactly what you're doing but drawImage is really fast, and can also draw canvas elements.